# Unexplainable reallocation? [Unrecognized selector sent to instance]

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know there are several questions on Stack regarding `Unrecognized selector..`, and I have experienced them myself sometimes, but this one is quite different.

I have two viewControllers, `MainViewController` and `ModalViewController`. The latter is shown modally on top of the first. `ModalViewController` contains (amongst other things) a `UITextField` and a `UITextView`.

After clicking a button on `MainViewController`, `ModalViewController` is presented, and the user can tap inside either text-element to write. This is working perfectly. Why shouldn't it..

The problem occurs if I present the view modally, then dismiss it, then present it again. The view is successfully presented, but if the user tries to tap inside either text-element, it crashes with the error 
`Unrecognized selector sent to instance [...] [SomeClass responderDidBecomeActive:]`. The `SomeClass` for the receiving instance changes each time, I have seen it as `UITouch`, `UITapAndAHalfRecognizer` and `__NSCFData`. Sometimes it doesn't even throw the error, just crashes with `(lldb)` (Bad access).

From what I gather of the error, it seems that my app is trying to call the method `responderDidBecomeActive:` on the `UITextView` or `UITextField`, but that something else has been allocated it that space?

The thing is: The first instance of `ModalViewController` gets deallocated before showing the second instance. They have nothing to do with each other. However, it seems like my device somehow remembers where the last instance of text-element was, instead of using the new instance. Why?

This makes no sense to me at all. I'm using ARC.

There is too much code involved to successfully reproduce this, but this is basically what happens:

`MainViewController.m`:

```
ModalViewController *m = 
        [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"modalView"];
m.customDelegate = self;
[m setCustomObject: customObject];
[m setModalTransitioningStyle: UIModal..CoverVertical];
[self presentViewController:m animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Can any of these have anything to do with this thing? The delegate perhaps? I just don't understand how these two events differ from each other when the first instance is completely deallocated.

**Note**

this only happens with the text-elements (`UITextView`/`UITextField`). There are other elements that always work as expected, such as a `UISlider`, `UIButton`, etc.

So.. This only happens when it wants to show the Keyboard. Why?

This is happening on both iOS7/iPhone5s and iOS8/iPhone6.

Comment: Show the code for dismiss, how the delegate is cleared up and any completion block code

Comment: @Wain The dismiss is simply on a button-action: `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`. This is the only thing I'm doing. I have never heard of 'clearing up a delegate', can you explain? It would make sense if that's the problem, for the whole 'custom delegate' is the only thing I'm relatively new to in this entire case. I assumed the delegate would be cleared when the `ModalView` deallocated. And the instantiation of `ModalView` inside `MainView` exists only inside a single void. Should I store the instantiation of the Modal view and clear the customDelegate later?

Comment: When dismissing you should nil the delegate and ensure that any first responder is cancelled

Comment: @Wain I have now added `self.delegate = nil;` right before the dismissal in my 'cancel'-action. It is still happening :/   I simply can't wrap my head around this. The `MainView` has no pointer/reference to the `ModalView` in any methods other than in the `-(IBAction)` its created in. When the `Modal`-view is deallocated shouldn't everything be as if it wasn't ever presented? There should be no leftovers in the `Main`-view indicating that a `Modal`-view was ever presented?

Comment: @Wain By the way, as it always is the selector `responderDidBecomeActive` thats sent to the wrong instance, it means that `Modal`-views instance of `UITextView` is corrupt? Or moved. I am using `Storyboard` to create the view, and I have ctrl-dragged the connection to my header-file (not as a @property, but directly in the brackets under @interface) as `__weak IBOutlet UITextView *txtTitle;` In my `viewDidLoad` I'm setting the textViews's delegate to `self`, but that might not have anything to do with this.. `viewDidLoad` IS getting fired the second time, so the textview's delegate IS set..

Comment: Should all be separate instances, but you seem to have some lingering connection between something still on screen, possibly from an unsafe unretained delegate somewhere. It's hard to tell really. Turn on zombies

Comment: @Wain Thank you, this lead me to the problem. I am using an external thing called `DAKeyboardControl` which easily allows me to get a 'drag finger down over keyboard to hide it'-thing, like in the Messages app. When removing that single line of code it started working. Bummer though, cause I really liked that feature.. Oh well. With Zombies turned on I started getting the same error in debug every time: `-[UIView responderDidBecomeActive:]: message sent to deallocated instance`, which made me realize I only had one tool that actually connects my `self.view` to the keyboard.  Thanks.

Comment: And yes.. Of course this was my fault! Stupid me.. This `DAKeyboardControl` obviously has a method I should've called when dismissing the controller. I now implemented it on viewWillDisappear (`[self.view removeKeyboardControl];`) and it works like a charm.